# How to design this following structure in Java?

Tags: java

I have an interface named `SHAPE`. `CIRCLE` and `RECTANGLE` are two classes implementing this interface. Now I have to write a class (i have an option to write a class only) `CIRCULARRECTANGLE` which will extend the properties of `CIRCLE` and `RECTANGLE`. How to do this in Java?

Comment: I think the common method here is `area()`. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since Java extends one class at a time, you will need to create abstract classes to fit your criteria.

Example:

```
public abstract class AbstractRectangle extends Rectangle {

public abstract class AbstractCircularRectangle extends AbstractRectangle {

public class CircularRectangle extends AbstractCircularRectangle {
```

---

**Update:** My first attempt will **never** work, hence my update:

Since my first attempt **never** extended a `Circle`, you will need to keep reference to eiter a `Circle` or a `Rectangle` like so:

```
public class CircularRectangle extends Rectangle {

    private Circle circle;

    public CircularRectangle(Circle circle) {
        this.circle = circle;
    }

    // Some logic:
}
```

The purpose of the constructor is to keep reference to a circle.

Comment: But you aren't extending Circle!?

Answer (score 3):

You can't do this directly. A Java class can always only extend a single class.

You *could* use delegation to get a similar effect. Your `CircularRectangle` (whatever that may represent!) could *reference* a `Circle` and a `Rectangle` object and "present" their properties as its own.

Comment: Well, the question is ambiguous. You don't know how `SHAPE` looks like

Comment: @Op: that's why I didn't comment further on whether this is useful or not.

Answer (score 3):

We can't define a class that **is-a** `Circle` and a `Rectangle` - as long as both entities are classes.

To solve a problem where this kind of schizophrenic behaviour is desired, we can consider using the adapter pattern (assuming, we have a Circle and Rectangle *interface* and concrete implementations)

```
public class CircleImpl implements Circle {

  // fields, constructors, implemented Circle methods

 public Object adapt(Class<? extends Shape> adaptee) {

   if (adaptee == Rectangle.class) {
     return new Rectangle() {
        // implemented rectangle methods so that
        // we have a squared circle
     };
   }
   return null;
 }
}
```

Comment: +1 for pointing out that a `CircularRectangle` is neither a `Cirle` nor a `Rectangle` so should not extend either - a common inheritence misconception.

Answer (score 2):

Java does not allow multiinheritance,perhaps you can do in using composition :

`CIRCULARRECTANGLE` implements `SHAPE` .

`CIRCULARRECTANGLE`  also contains an instance of `CIRCLE` and `RECTANGLE` .Then you implement the methods of `CIRCULARRECTANGLE` using this two instances according to your logic.

Answer (score 1):

I would define 2 interfaces Circle and Rectangle. You classes will implement these interfaces. Then you can define interface CircularRectangle extending both interfaces. 
The tridr class CircularRectangle should have 2 instances cirlceInstance and rectangleInstance and delegate calls invoking necesary methods from the instances.

Answer (score 0):

As java doesn't allow multiple inheritance, this is just not possible. You cannot let a class extend more than one superclass.
Try using composition instead of inheritance.